# How to count number of non distinct results?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm getting a list of objects from a model with a generic relation.

```
point_list = Point.objects.filter(Q(content_type=ct1,object_id__in=answer_list) | Q(content_type=ct2,object_id__in=link_list))
```

Now I actually don't want to have all the point objects, but instead I want to have the distinct results and the count of how many duplicate points are there. (for me the point object is the same if it linked to the same "content_object")

The point of this would be to sort the point_list by number of duplicates and then accessing the content_object. This would effectively give me a list of content_objects sorted by how many points they have received.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct elements in a list, you can try set():

```
print set(point_list)
```

Try something like this:

```
import collections

a = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6]

counts = collections.Counter(a)
print counts # Counter({4: 3, 5: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 6: 1})
```

Output is a dict.

Comment: It shows up in the result presented by PEJK. Basically Counter is a dict for which the key is the object, the value is the count of that object (# of times he's present)